# nginx proxy redirection with port from uri

Tags: regex, redirect, nginx

I'm trying to make redirections using nginx. The idea is to redirect uri /id_1234/ to localhost:1234 for some ports. The redirection for the fixed port:

```
location /id_1234/ {
    rewrite ^/id_1234/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:1234;
    proxy_redirect http://localhost:1234/ $scheme://$host/id_1234/;
}
```

It works just fine. Now I try to change 1234 to any port:

```
location ~* ^/id_([0-9]*)/ {
    rewrite ^/id_([0-9]*)/(.*)$ /$2 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:$1;
    proxy_redirect http://localhost:$1/ $scheme://$host/id_$1/;
}
```

With this config, I get a 502 error, with the following error in log:

```
no resolver defined to resolve localhost
```

If I change $1 to actual port after localhost:, it works fine for the specified port. How can be redirection port specified using regex?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding

```
resolver 127.0.0.1;
```

helps, but it's very strange...

Comment: Does not work for me: `[error] 7#7: send() failed (111: Connection refused) while resolving, resolver: 127.0.0.1:53`

Comment: @FelikZ On my Ubuntu 20.04 server, I had to use `resolver 127.0.0.53;`. Run `cat /etc/resolv.conf` to check the IP of your nameserver(s).

Answer (score 5):

Following up from @alleb57's answer - it appears that there just isn't a definition for `localhost` at this point of the configuration. I converted to using `http://127.0.0.1` throughout the config (over `localhost`) and you don't have to define the resolver.