# Using nginx regex location matching to dynamically map URI's to different ports for multiple reverse proxies

Tags: reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I'm using nginx to create a reverse proxy to a web app that may be behind a firewall. For my initial proof of concept I used the following location block to ensure it worked.

```
    location / {
            proxy_pass https://localhost:2222;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
```

I open up my reverse tunnel on my web app with `ssh -f -N -T -R2222:localhost:443 user@nginx-ip`.
This works exactly as I like. I type in my `nginx-ip` into my browser and I get the https traffic from my web app but obfuscated by the `nginx-ip`, etc.

I want to allow potentially a few thousand reverse tunnels though across a few thousand ports (instead of just 2222 in the above case). Reading up on nginx, [I thought to use regular expressions](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) to dynamically use a URI containing the port number to proxy_pass to that specific port.

That is, I'd like `https://nginx-ip/2222/` to `proxy_pass https://localhost:2222;` and I'd like `https://nginx-ip/1111/` to `proxy_pass https://localhost:1111;`.

I've tried quite a few variations, but as far as I've been able to reason, I've landed on thinking this should work:

```
    location ~* ^/(\d+) {
            proxy_pass https://localhost:$1;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
```

It doesn't. I get a 502 Bad Gateway in my browser and the error log gives me:

> 2016/05/31 21:02:36 [error] 6188#0: *3584 no resolver defined to resolve localhost, client: {my-client-ip}, server: localhost, request: "GET /2222/ HTTP/1.1", host: "{nginx-ip}"

When I use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` I get a 404. The webpage says

> Not Found
>   The requested URL /2222/ was not found on this server.

Is what I'm attempting possible with nginx configuration?

To reiterate, I would like to be able to initiate many (thousands) unique reverse tunnels through an nginx web server. My initial thought was to vary the outgoing ports of the nginx server based on what other web app I want to proxy through, and to assign the request to my nginx server to a different port by a port in the URI (extracting it via regex).

Comment: Is the 404 error coming from the backend server (the one that opened the `ssh` tunnel)? If so, you probably need to add a [url-rewriting rule like the one in this answer](http://serverfault.com/a/379679/123520) to remove the `/2222`.

Comment: Ooh! Yes it is! I didn't realize that at first. Thanks!

Comment: Of note: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25106424/nginx-proxy-redirection-with-port-from-uri) is very similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve my problem, and with the help of @Cirdec I ended up going a different direction.

Instead of using path in the URI to reference port, I was successful using the port as a subdomain. That is, `1111.my-host-name` will send things through the reverse proxy on `127.0.0.1` (`localhost`) on port `1111`. This requires enlisting some DNS wildcarding to help with some of the heavy listing (of note: wildcard DNS matching in `/etc/hosts` will not work, but you can hard code a few entries to test that it works.

Excerpt from my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
nginx-box-ip-address     2222.my-host-name
nginx-box-ip-address     1111.my-host-name
```

This paired with nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name ~^(?<port_subdomain>[0-9]*).my-host-name$;

    # NOTE: omitted extra ssl configuration lines

    location / {
            proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:$port_subdomain;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

Now I can have my web app open up reverse proxy tunnels to arbitrary ports on my nginx box (my-host-name) and reach them through a subdomain.

An step by step example:

- On one of my web app boxes, I open up a reverse tunnel to port `2222` on my nginx box (my-host-name) with `ssh -f -N -T -R2222:localhost:443 user@my-host-name`

  - On a different web app box I can open up a different tunnel to the same nginx box (my-host-name), say port `1111` by running `ssh -f -N -T -R1111:localhost:443 user@my-host-name` on the different web app box
- On my nginx box, I have loaded the config above. I open up chrome and hit `2222.my-host-name` and it is as if I'm directly hitting the URL/IP address of my web app box (only it can be behind a firewall thanks to the reverse proxy). Hitting `1111.my-host-name` takes me to the other web app box, that is completely separate and through a completely separate tunnel.

Comment: Warning use 127.0.1 not localhost in proxy_pass

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with a combination of a [url-rewriting rule](https://serverfault.com/a/379679/123520) to remove the digits specifying the port and a [named capture](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) to extract the `requested_port` as a usable variable for the `proxy_pass` directive.

```
    location ~* ^/(?<requested_port>\d+) {
            rewrite /(\d+)(.*) /$1  break;
            proxy_pass https://localhost:$requested_port;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
```

Comment: I want to do almost the same thing (I have the port on the URL like img/PORT/otherstuf). I tried your way but it does not work. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

```
location ~ ^/proxy(?<requested_port>\d+)(?<proxy_uri>/.*) {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$requested_port$proxy_uri$is_args$args;
}
```

this is a example url https://noisy.ltd/proxy9023/api/1.0/FacMonitor/open/listExpand
now it is working