# How can I keep port and url without updating Gitlab nginx?

Tags: nginx, gitlab, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

nginx(ng1): 172.168.240.5

Gitlab includ nginx (ng2): 172.168.240.55

ng1 config

```
listen       81;
server_name  ng1;
location /gitlab/ {
    proxy_pass 172.168.240.55/
}
```

how can I keep port and url without updating ng2. // only modify ng1

## url gitlab lost

it's login(POST) http://ng1:81/gitlab/users/sign_in

but it's show http://ng1:81/users/sign_in instead of http://ng1:81/gitlab/users/sign_in

it seems to be rewrite by ng2

## url gitlab and port lost

click one file in http://ng1:81/gitlab/root/pg/

but it's http://ng1/root/pg/index.html instead of http://ng1:81/gitlab/root/pg/index.html

Comment: You post is a bit unclear. You are getting `http://ng1/root/pg/index.html` instead of `http://ng1:81/gitlab/root/pg/index.html`?

Comment: yes http://ng1/root/pg/index.html instead of http://ng1:81/gitlab/root/pg/index.html,it's seem to be rewrite by gitlab(ng2),but we only modify (ng1)

Comment: See if the config listed in this article helps? https://medium.com/@gdurelle/gitlab-behind-a-reverse-proxy-nginx-5245476747fe

Comment: it seems to modify Gitlab in
https://medium.com/@gdurelle/gitlab-behind-a-reverse-proxy-nginx-5245476747fe

Answer (score 0):

need nginx reverse proxy
/servername/port/ for dynamic servername and port

I find resolve (dns server + nginx)
[Using nginx regex location matching to dynamically map URI's to different ports for multiple reverse proxies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37555674/using-nginx-regex-location-matching-to-dynamically-map-uris-to-different-ports)