# nginx capture port number from uri and set up proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Following [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/536576/nginx-how-do-i-forward-an-http-request-to-another-port) I can successfully load the ports manually. For example, using the following nginx.conf:

```
location /port {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5001;
}
```

I would have to manually create the locations if I wanted to redirect and range of ports (5001-5228). To avoid this I want to capture the port number using the regex approach.
I tried is the following:

```
location ~^/port/(.*)$ {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:$1;
    add_header X-debug-message "input: $1" always;
    add_header X-debug-message-2 "request_uri: $request_uri" always;
    add_header X-uri "uri: $uri" always;
}
```

The response headers I get from this implementation are:
`Content-Type: text/html Server: nginx/1.17.3 X-Debug-Message: input: 5002 X-Debug-Message-2: request_uri: /port/5002 X-Uri: uri: /port/5002`

Nginx Logs shows:
`error 4512#4512: \*1 no resolver defined to resolve localhost`

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25106424/nginx-proxy-redirection-with-port-from-uri)
I set up my resolver to 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1 and what /etc/resolv.conf shows
but either returns no resolver or `*1 localhost could not be resolved (110: Operation timed out)`

I have also tried with the following options inside

```
location ~^/port/(.*)$ /{
    ...
    rewrite /port/(.\*) $1 break;
    set $upstream http://localhost:$1;
    proxy_pass $upstream;
}
```

This returns:
`Content-Type: text/html Server: nginx/1.17.3 X-Debug-Message: input: 5002 X-Debug-Message-2: request_uri: /port/5002 X-Uri: uri: 5002`

Nginx Logs Shows:
`error 4638#4638: \*5 invalid URL prefix in ""`

How can I setup the nginx.conf location block such that a call with /port/50xx will be redirected to the localhost with port?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question. Keeping this open for others stumbling across similar issue.
I ended up using the following:

```
location ~^/port/(?<port>\d+)/(.*)$ {
        resolver 127.0.0.1;
        set $upstream "http://127.0.0.1:$port";
        proxy_pass $upstream/$2$is_args$args;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
```

Something I learned was to assign the $port variable by the location `(?<port>\d+)` and create a backend string with your uri. Then proxy pass that backend variable. The resolver issue was fixed by moving the resolver into the location block.